# Finding average using group by clause in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
+--------------+  
| month | year |  
+-------+------+  
| jan   | 2015 |  
| jan   | 2015 |  
| jan   | 2015 |  
| feb   | 2015 |  
| feb   | 2015 |  
| feb   | 2015 |  
| feb   | 2015 |  
| feb   | 2015 |  
| mar   | 2015 |  
| mar   | 2015 |  
| mar   | 2015 |  
| mar   | 2015 |  
| mar   | 2015 |  
| mar   | 2015 |  
| mar   | 2015 |  
| mar   | 2016 |  
| mar   | 2016 |  
| mar   | 2016 |  
| mar   | 2016 |  
| mar   | 2016 |  
| mar   | 2016 |  
| mar   | 2016 |  
| mar   | 2016 |  
| feb   | 2016 |  
| feb   | 2016 |  
| jan   | 2016 |  
| jan   | 2016 |  
| jan   | 2016 |  
| jan   | 2016 |  
+--------------+
```

This is the table.

I need avg rate of every month (i.e month/year)

Comment: avg rate of each month for particular year . I mean jan/2015,jan/2016,feb/2015.....

Comment: Please share your code or whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: i created a view to store the count of each year,as i need to calculate count(month of particular year / total count of year).but i have no idea how to use it

Comment: i created view so it has count if each year. 2015-18 && 2016 - 20(as we need count of each year to calculate month/year). and this query gives count of each month for particular year-- select count(*) as num,month,year from crate group by month,year;  now i have to count the rate of each montha of particular year.i have no idea how proceed next. @KrutiPatel

Comment: @lucky: `select count(month) as num,month,year from crate group by month,year;` This query will give you count of month in particular year.

Comment: It worked .. thank you @KrutiPatel

Comment: @lucky: I have posted as an answer for future reference. You can accept the same if its an answer of your question.

Comment: I need to caculate the month rate,i mean count of jan is 3 in 2015 and total records for 2015 are 18.Now i need to calculate the month rate(i.e 3/18) @KrutiPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should count `month` column instead of `*`.

**Here is the query:**

```
SELECT (COUNT(my.`month`)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM crate inmn WHERE inmn.`year` = my.`year`)) AS num, my.`month`, my.`year` FROM crate my GROUP BY my.`month`,my.`year;
```

Above query will give a average of `month` in particular `year`.

Comment: what does my and inmn represent here?

Comment: Its just an alias for table as I am using same table twise.